# how to draw a 'x' shape like below

Tags: python

I am new to python, please someone help to draw a shape like below. The program have to take the number of star as an input.

number of star = 7

```
*      *
**    **
***  *** 
********
***  *** 
**    **
*      *
```

My code:

```
count = int(input('star count : '))
pattern_size = count + 1
for t in range(1, pattern_size):
    pattern = list(" " * pattern_size)
    pattern[:t] = "*" * t
    pattern[-t:] = '*' * t
    print(''.join(pattern))

star count :  9
*        *
**      **
***    ***
****  ****
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
```

Comment: Show us the code that you have tried. People will happy to help you if you are stuck somewhere.

Comment: count = int(input('star count : '))
pattern_size = count + 1
for t in range(1, pattern_size):
    pattern = list(" " * pattern_size)
    pattern[:t] = "*" * t
    pattern[-t:] = '*' * t
    print(t,''.join(pattern))

Comment: Can you please add that code in your question?

Comment: A tip: it will be way simpler if you used two loops

Comment: separate loops for iterating and printing star??

Comment: @JohnMullar You just will finish it yourself: add one variable to control output, `len_t = t if t <= pattern_size / 2 else  pattern_size - t`, then output by len `pattern[:len_t] and pattern[-len_t:]`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a easy-to-understand example using two for-loops with your approach: One just the inverse of another

```
count = int(input('star count : '))
pattern_size = count + 1
for t in range(1, int(pattern_size/2)):
    pattern = list(" " * pattern_size)
    pattern[:t] = "*" * t
    pattern[-t:] = '*' * t
    print(''.join(pattern))

for t in range(int(pattern_size/2), 0, -1):
    pattern = list(" " * pattern_size)
    pattern[:t] = "*" * t
    pattern[-t:] = '*' * t
    print(''.join(pattern))
```

And a more advanced method would be to use the string method `.center()` like so:

```
count = int(input('star count : '))
pattern_size = count + 1
for t in range(1, int(pattern_size/2)):
    print((" " * (pattern_size-t*2)).center(pattern_size, '*'))
for t in range(int(pattern_size/2), 0, -1):
    print((" " * (pattern_size - t * 2)).center(pattern_size, '*'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just like my comment, this is the complete code:

```
count = int(input('star count : '))
pattern_size = count + 1
for t in range(1, pattern_size):
    pattern = list(" " * pattern_size)
    len_t = t if t <= (pattern_size / 2) else (pattern_size - t)
    pattern[:len_t] = "*" * len_t
    pattern[-len_t:] = '*' * len_t
    print(''.join(pattern))
```

Hope this help.